# C# using System.Windows.Forms does not exist

Tags: c#

I tried to add:

```
using System.Windows.Forms
```

But its shows me an error.

I know I must assembly that to my VS2012 but I srsly don't know how. I was searching everywhere and tried everything I've found but none of this helps me.

@edit
1 hour of searching in the web and... 2 minutes after write this post i found...
Project >> add Reference...

Solved :]

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: That's nice, how do you solve it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're using **Visual Studio**, right click the References folder in your project, select Add Reference... and then on the .NET tab, choose System.Windows.Forms and click OK.

Comment: I'm using VS2015 and searching for that brings up nothing when following your steps.

Answer (score 5):

Right click on project references in Solution Explorer, choose Add Reference..., there you have to find System.Windows.Forms assembly (under Assemblies=>Framework) and add it to the project.

Answer (score 0):

## For people with .NET 6.0:

Add this to your `.csproj` file (click on the file named after your project in Solution Explorer) before the `</Project>`:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
</PropertyGroup>
```